# Spring security requireSecure redirect loop

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Default logout method, with below configuration produces, redirects to HTTP url. when I add `.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()` it goes into redirect loop. As I understand this is because spring sends out HTTPS request, tomcat makes it into http request and then spring again tries to do https request and that's the looping? Not sure. This looping happens at root url.

I have tried adding

```
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header = x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header = x-forwarded-proto
server.use-forward-headers: true
```

to properties file but it had no effect.

```
httpSecurity
    .csrf().disable()
    .anonymous()
        .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new OowAccessDeniedEntryPoint())
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(ignoreStaticResourceMatchers()).permitAll()
        .antMatchers(ignoreEndpointMatchers()).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .oauth2Login()
        .and()
    .rememberMe()
        .key(key)
        .rememberMeServices(new OowTokenBasedRememberMeServices(key, cookies, encrypt, gson))
        .and()
    .logout()
```

Currently planning todo a workaround to this problem, but I'm a little amazed that I haven'd found a solution to this problem after 6 hours of scraping the web.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround was

```
static class OowLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.debug("Logout success"); 
    }
}
```

But I feel that the below code solved the issue.

(1) application.yml

```
server:
  use-forward-headers: true
```

(2) in servers `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/oow.com-le-ssl.conf`

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
```

(2.1) and enabled the apache module with

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

Put it together with the help of [this](https://medium.com/@codebyamir/using-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-f704da73e7c8) and [this](https://ycsoftware.net/invalid-command-requestheader-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-module/)